# Is there any way I can write this in a better/optimized way

Tags: sql

I am trying to execute the following stored procedure, it takes forever to execute it for more records. Is there any way I can write this in a better/optimized way

```
DECLARE productcursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT ProductId,
       product_startdate 
FROM   Products
WHERE  ProductStatus IN ('F', 'R', 'M')
GROUP BY productId

OPEN productcursor
FETCH NEXT FROM productcursor INTO @var_PId,@var_PStartDate
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN

SELECT @var_count = count(*) FROM   Products
    WHERE  ProductID IN ((
    SELECT ProductID FROM   Products
        WHERE  ProductStatus IN ('OR', 'OP')
        AND    Comments LIKE '%CANCELLED%'
        except (  SELECT ProductID FROM   Products WHERE  ProductStatus = 'DE'
                   UNION
                   SELECT ProductID FROM   Products WHERE  ProductStatus = 'OR' AND  Comments NOT LIKE '%CANCELLED%'
                   ))                
        except (    SELECT ProductID FROM   Products
        WHERE  ProductStatus IN ('RE', 'C', 'S', 'D')
                   ))
                   and productid = @var_PId

                   if @var_count = 0
                     INSERT INTO ProductDel
                      (ProductID, ProductDate, ProductDelStatus)
               VALUES (@var_PID, @var_PStartDate, 'UNKNOWN')
                   else
                     INSERT INTO ProductDel
                      (ProductID, ProductDate, ProductDelStatus)
               VALUES (@var_PID, @var_PStartDate, 'INService')
FETCH NEXT FROM productcursor INTO @var_PId,@var_PStartDate
END
Close productcursor
Deallocate productcursor
```

As suggested, I am able to make this work without cursor but still it takes forever to execute this... more than 2 hrs for million records
Here is sql fiddle link for this
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b14eb/56

Comment: Don't use cursor, it will be much better

Comment: In Products table two columns ProductID and product_id ? cause you written and product_id = @var_PId in query. If it is ProductID instead of product_id then there is no meaning of IN query cause you taken products which have status 'F','R' and 'M' which will not matach with status 'OR' and 'OP' status

Comment: Sorry, its a typo. There is no product_id, only ProductId. I fixed it

Comment: Also would like to add ProductId is not unique here

Comment: r u using sql server 2008/2012 or mySql????